# Graph API Batch Request. Error (#803)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request

I need to get friends' albums with photos. Do that with batch query (coz https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

```
[ 
 { "method":"GET",
   "name":"get-friends",
   "relative_url":"me/friends?fields=id,name",
   "omit_response_on_success": false
 },
 {
   "method":"GET",
   "name":"get-albums",
   "relative_url":"{result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}/albums",
   "omit_response_on_success": false
 },
 {
   "method":"GET",
   "name":"get-photos",
   "relative_url":"{result=get-albums:$.data.*.id}/photos"
 }
]
```

But in response i got error.This is response:

```
[
  {
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "xxxx",
         "name": "Name Lastname"
      },{
         "id": "xxxx",
         "name": "Name2 Lastname"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/xxx/friends?fields=id,name&format=json&access_token=xxx&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_xxx"
   },
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 4
   }
}"
  },
  {
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "1 Photos",
         "created_time": "2012-11-22T04:22:46+0000",
         "id": "xxx"
      },
      {
         "name": "2 Pictures",
         "created_time": "2010-09-12T02:48:42+0000",
         "id": "xxx"
      },
      {
         "name": "3 Personal",
         "created_time": "2007-10-25T15:59:06+0000",
         "id": "xxx"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "after": "NTc0NyQxMzkwOQ==",
         "before": "MTAxNTuyNjIzMzQwMDg5MTA="
      }
   }
}"
  },
  {
    "code": 404,
    "body": "{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: xxx,xxx,xxx",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}"
  }
]
```

Please tell me where is my mistake or tell me another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t get access to albums of friends, all friend permissions have been removed with v2.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

You can only get access to albums of users who authorized your App (with `user_photos`, of course).

Comment: Thanks)  but why do they complicate all :\ FQL will be deleted, and are not all can solve by Batch Requests (as i can see, BQ is not easy way for complex queries, and not fast).
Maybe i can get only authorized friends (in App) for to pass error?

Comment: it´s less complicated actually, FQL was a pain and you should not be able to get data of users who did not even authorize your app for privacy reasons ;)